# broadcasting — multiply a (NxN) array by a (M) array to have a (NxNxM) array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two `numpy`'s *ndarrays*

```
a.shape # -> (3, 3)
b.shape # -> (5,)
```

and I want to compute a `c` array, defined by

```
c.shape # -> (3, 3, 5)
c[...,i] = a*b[i]
```

(the exact shape of `c` is unimportant because I can always transpose its axes).

It seems to me that posting my coding attempts so far would be unnecessarily embarrassing, it's something like many variations on `a[:,None,:]*b[None,:]` and that's enough said, isn't it?

I suspect that `np.einsum()` could be the answer, but the syntax of its subscripts command flies above my head...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice solution is to use the fantastic [`einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) function:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> b = np.array([10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000])
>>> c = np.einsum('ij,k->ijk', a, b)
>>> c[1, 2, 3]
60000
>>> a[1, 2]
6
>>> b[3]
10000
```

I like it because it makes the transform `ij,k -> ijk` very explicit. Also possible, and more concise, is to use simple broadcasting:

```
>>> c = a[:, :, None] * b[None, None, :]
>>> c.shape
(3L, 3L, 5L)
```

Where you use `:` to use a dimension, `None` to broadcast along one.

Comment: I prefer the broadcasting part of your answer, I've found it rather enlightening (finally I've spotted the right pattern!) but both parts are correct and I've got my results... thanks a lot.

Comment: I  understand **now** that what I really wanted and what I want is `c.shape -> (5, 3, 3)` but having spotted the pattern (finally!) it's as easy as `a[None,:,:]*b[:,None,None]` — thank you again.

Comment: `einsum` really requires that 'aha !' moment when you realise that `a[i, j] * b[k] = c[i, j, k]` translates directly to `einsum('ij , k -> ijk', ...)`. Although one could argue it's overkill for simple broadcasting, I love it all the same...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be with [`np.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) as basically we are performing outer product there. Now, `np.outer` expects the inputs to be `1D` arrays and as the pre-processing step it flattens the inputs before performing elementwise multiplication. So, the output from `np.outer(a,b)` would be `2D` and we need to reshape it to desired `3D` shape. Thus, the final implementation would look something like this -

```
np.outer(a,b).reshape(a.shape+(-1,))
```

A more explicit way to do the reshaping would be like so -

```
np.outer(a,b).reshape(a.shape+b.shape)
```